# How to avoid that swiping a SwipeableContainer also creates an event in the top container?

Tags: codenameone

When I have a SwipeableContainer with a Button in the top container (not the underlying container you reveal by swiping), swiping the container left also pushes that button.

Can you help with how to set this up so the SwipeableContainer consumes the click and doesn't send it to the button as well?

Thanks for any help.

The problem is shown in the example below: swiping left most often also triggers a click on the "Press to see details" button which immediately makes the leftSwipeCont disappear and also hides/unhides the "Hideable details".

Here is the code example to see this (copy into a HelloWorld example):

```
hi = new Form("Hi World", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Container hideable = new Container();
hideable.add("Hideable details");
hideable.setHidden(true);
Container cont = new Container(new BorderLayout());
cont.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, hideable);
Button button = new Button("Press me to see details"); //shouldn't be pressed when the container is just swiped!!
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        hideable.setHidden(!hideable.isHidden());
        hideable.animateLayout(300);
    }
});
cont.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);
Container leftSwipeCont = new Container();
leftSwipeCont.add(new Button("XX"));
SwipeableContainer swipe = new SwipeableContainer(leftSwipeCont, cont);
hi.add(swipe);
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of "black magic":

```
button.setAutoRelease(true);
```

By default if you drag your finger within the button itself it won't release its grip as it assumes you still want to press it. This handles complex cases like over sensitive screens that detect drag when there is none.

However, in this case we need the code to be less sensitive.

Comment: And the black humor that goes with it ;-)
Thanks, it works. I guess I wouldn't have been able to figure that out via the documentation.

Comment: It's there in the javadoc but sometimes you need to know where to look. That's true for every huge framework...